# How to escape exclamation point in weback.config.js string so as not to cause error from Terser

Tags: javascript, webpack, terser

I need to set an external dependency that has an exclamation point in its name to Webpack's webpack.config.js (or figure out a better way to have Webpack ignore this dependency while bundling) due to this dependency not being accessible until runtime.

Here is how I am attempting to set this dependency as an external in my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/output',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  externals: {
    baja: 'baja!'
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the dependency's name or how it is accessed. But the exclamation point causes an error when Webpack tries to transpile.

The error that I get when attempting to build with webpack is:

> ERROR in bundle.js from Terser
>
> Unexpected token: operator (!) [bundle.js:1595,21]

If I remove the exclamation point from the string, it no longer errors out, so this is definitely where the problem lies. Adding a backslash prior to the exclamation point does not fix this problem-- is there another option similar to this to escape the character for Terser's purposes? Or is there another way I can ask Webpack to ignore the dependency that wouldn't be hindered by the exclamation point? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is similar as the problem other people had: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5320. So I don't think you can fix this other than renaming the dependency or using a different one.